# InfoPath: How to show filed value instead of display name for the dropdown box options on Email submissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Let's say I have a dropdown box with the following options -

Display Name: The Golden State    | Value: California | 
Display Name: Old Dominion        | Value: Virginia | 
Display Name: The Lone Star State | Value: Texas |

When users fill out the form, they see and pick the display name, after they submit the form the submission is sent via Email. How do I go about making the response to show the Values in the email instead of their Display names?

Comment: What mechanism are you using to send the email?

Comment: using InfoPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you set the submit option to send email with the form as attachment after submitting?

If that's the case, the form in the email will show display name as the form when editing in InfoPath.

As a workaround, I suggest you publishing the drop down field to list as a column, then use workflow in SharePoint Designer and "Send an email" action, then lookup the drop down field in the email body.

Comment: The email is sent with no attachment, just plain text/table on the email body. I assume WF would work to pick things up and report the values conditionally. Thanks.